# Is it possible to copy all the members of one type to another without explicitly mentioning each one?

Tags: struct, syntax, rust

I have two structs that have mostly the same keys. Is it possible to copy all the keys without explicitly mentioning each one? Is there a cleaner way of doing this:

```
struct Type1<'a> {
    field1: i32,
    field2: &'a str,
    field3: &'a str,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Type2<'a> {
    field1: i32,
    field2: &'a str,
}

fn example() {
    let t1 = Type1 {
        field1: 1,
        field2: "A",
        field3: "B",
    };
    let t2 = Type2 {
        field1: t1.field1,
        field2: t1.field2,
    };
    println!("{:?}", t2);
}
```

Comment: You could implement the `From` trait: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html

Comment: @UnholySheep Semi-related question, is there any runtime overhead by doing so?